# Will developing a PhoneGap/Cordova iPhone app on an old XCode IDE+laptop affect my App Market sales?

Tags: android, iphone, app-store, cordova

I want to publish my PhoneGap-Cordova app on the Apple Market now that I'm live on the Android Market ([Puzzles For Friends](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.puzzlesforfriends.free)), but my Apple Laptop is **OLD**, (XCode from OSX Lion).  This made me use PhoneGap/Cordova 1.9 for the Apple version of the app - to be compliant with my old XCode (The Android App uses PhoneGap-Cordova 2.5).

**My question is**: If I publish this app to the Apple App Store from my **OLD** Apple Laptop using **OSX Lion** - is it going to **HURT** my App's **number of downloads**? Or will everyone with the latest and greatest OSX iPhones/iPads be just as likely to download my app just as much as if I developed on newer OSX versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently can not build and submit apps to the iOS App Store using an Xcode version older than Xcode 4.5, which requires a Mac running a newer release of OS X than Lion.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the OS and machine you are developing on is irrelevant to app downloads.

The person downloading the app never sees this information. The marketplaces don't store this information.